# Why does my program act different when using different editors and compilers?

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to ask the user for a set amount of values then again ask the user for the values, sort them, and then the user will enter a value. The program is supposed to search for this value and either return the position of the value or tell the user that it is not a part of the list he gave.

I used notepad++ and pocketc++ to run and compile the whole program then I transferred this a UNIX editor, putty and g++ and this is where I ran into problems. When I used putty and g++, the program compiled fine, but would only return the value sorted in the middle. For example I want 3 numbers, 1 2 3. Then I ask the program where 2 is, it returns 2 is in the second position but any other number will give me a junk value. This is only in putty and c++, while pocketc++ will work with all values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char answer;
    int list,target, first, last;
    int *array;
    int search(int , int , int , int );
    int sort( int a[], int);
    int index_of_smallest(const int array[], int first, int target);
    void swap(int& v1, int& v2);
    int search(int data[], int target, int first, int last);

    cout << "How many integers does your list have?\n";
    cin >> list;
    array  = new int[list];
    cout << "Please enter your integers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < list; i++)
        cin >> array[i];

    do {
        cout << "\nWhat is the target value?\n";
        cin >> target;
        sort(array,list);
        first = 0;
        last = list-1;
        int k= search( array, target, first, last);
        if (k == -1) cout << "That number is not a part of your list of integers.\n";
        else cout << "The location of " << target << " is spot " << k+1 << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to search a different number?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    } while (answer !='n' && answer !='N');
    return 0;
}

int index_of_smallest(const int array[], int first, int target){
    int min= array[first];
    int index_min=first;
    for ( int i = first + 1; i < target; i++)
        if (array[i] < min) {min = array[i];
    index_min = i;}
    return index_min;
}

void swap(int& v1, int& v2){
    int temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1=v2;
    v2=temp;
}

void sort(int a[], int num){
    int next_smallest;
    for (int i= 0; i < num - 1; i++)
    {
        next_smallest =index_of_smallest(a, i, num);
        swap (a[i],a[next_smallest]);
    }
}

int search(int data[], int target, int first, int last) {
    int middle;
    if (first > last) 
        return -1;
    else {
        middle=(first + last)/2;
        if (target == data[middle])
            return middle;    
        else if ( target < data[middle])
            search(data, target, first, middle-1);
        else if (target > data[middle])
            search(data, target, middle +1, last);}
}
```

Comment: If different compilers give you different results, it's possible that you've invoked undefined behaviour (for instance, dereferencing a pointer at memory you haven't allocated, over or underflowing a buffer, etc) which compilers are allowed to code however they want, but in practice the results will depend upon how they decided to pack together memory on the stack and heap - which will vary from compilation to compilation.

Comment: Are thoose function declarations supposed to be inside the main function?

Comment: You need to improve the formatting of your code with a more conventional and consistent indenting style for others to read it.  Similarly, in C++ there is no need or reason to declare every variable at the start of your block.  Avoid `using namespace std`, especially when you go and use variables named `array` which is the name of a type in `std`.  Calling `new` and `delete` when you aren't writing a low level memory managing class is a common cause of memory corruption. Function forward declarations are conventionally put outside of functions in modern C++. Make a http://sscce.org/ please.

Comment: Try compiling with all warnings enabled. The compiler will say something interesting about the `search` function.

Comment: I moved the functions outside of main, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Sorry for my formatting I've only had a semester of c++ and the instructor says he will take off points for bad formatting but hasn't previously taken any off so I just stuck with it.

Comment: Listen to Raymond!  Another common mistake that makes me cringe:  `std::cin >> var` with no check that it's read a value successfully.  Try to use something like `if (std::cin >> var) use(var); else throw std::runtime_error("couldn't read var from cin!");`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While briefly looking over your code, nothing stood out that was exceptionally odd. That being said, if I run your code through a compiler, the following warning comes out:

```
[11:04pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] g++ -Wall foo.cc 
foo.cc: In function ‘int search(int*, int, int, int)’:
foo.cc:76: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

And so we look at the search function. It looks like you intended for the function to be recursive, and so I believe you should have written it with more return statements:

```
int search(int data[], int target, int first, int last) {
    int middle;
    if (first > last) 
        return -1;
    else {
        middle=(first + last)/2;
        if (target == data[middle])
            return middle;    
        else if ( target < data[middle])
            return search(data, target, first, middle-1);
        else if (target > data[middle])
            return search(data, target, middle +1, last);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my issue!! I forgot my returns!! Thanks you!! Thank you everyone else who was helping too!